# "Replace" transforms string to float. How to keep string format?

Tags: python, csv

I would like to remove smileys and an emoji from my twitter text corpus.
The script removes the smileys successfully. But when I use the file for the next analysis steps, the string got converted to float and this causes an error in the next steps. Without stripping off the emojis, the text is not float and causes no error in the next analysis steps. So the error is to be found in this script. Can I somehow change the script in a way that leaves the format as string?

the float that results are some lines in the output file:

```
<class 'str'> ""USERNAME Danke, Dir auch, beim Stabilisieren und Herumdoktern am Falschen ""
<class 'str'> ""USERNAME Also ich werde, sobald die Brille da ist, sagen, was ich von den Gläsern und co halte! ""
<class 'float'> nan

#remove emoticons 
with open("data_sentiment.csv","r", encoding="utf-8") as oldfile1, open("data_sentiment_stripped_emoticons.csv", 'w',encoding="utf-8") as newfile1:
    for line in oldfile1:
        line=line.replace("","").replace(":)", "").replace(":D", "").replace(":(","").replace(":-(","")
        newfile1.write(line)
newfile1.close()
```

Comment: use [raw string](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in this script. This script creates a text file which, by definition, does not contain floats.

The problem is in the script(/program/whatever) that end up reading the file that you're writing here. That second script will open the file and encounter a string like "2.6", which it then interprets as a number.

Comment: But if I do not remove the emojis with that said script, then the other file interprets the script correctly as a string.

Comment: That makes sense. No sensible script would interpret "2.6 :)" as a float. However, that doesn't mean that the script in your question is wrong to translate "2.6 :)" into "2.6". It's still a string - you just need to make your second script (the one that reads the new file, which you didn't post) not interpret strings as floats.